# Exclude border when using border-radius

Tags: css, border, rounded-corners

I have a `div` containing 2 `div`s:

```
<div>
    <div id="first">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="second">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to achieve the following behaviour:

- the parent div -> round corners
- child first div -> round corners at the top
- child second div -> round corners at the bottom
- between the parent div and the children -> borders from the children

**Expected**:

[image]

**Actual**:

[image]

Trying to get the expected image above, I used the following code for the blue div:

```
border-bottom: 10px solid green;
border-left: 10px solid green;
border-right: 10px solid green;

border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
```

and for the red div:

```
border-top: 10px solid green;
border-left: 10px solid green;
border-right: 10px solid green;

border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
```

The problem is that the `border-radius` is applied to the element including the `border`. So, because the wanted border-radius (5px) is less than the border (10px) for the red and blue divs, the corners of the read and blue are are not rounded.

I want to apply `border-radius` on the element **excluding** the `border`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you edit your question to show all relevant code and also an image of what you're result you're getting now? It's hard to understand what you want to achieve and what you're getting currently

Comment: @JayCodist, I added another picture. So I want to get the expectation, but I get the actual picture, because those `border-radius`es < `border`.

Comment: Could you show all the relevant CSS you're using for the divs?

Comment: Yes, I did it, only for the inner divs. Those are "tricky". 
The big one is just a simple `div` with a `border-radius`, nothing special.
The dilemma is how to round corners using border-radius if "the rounding" comes into the existing "border" (green).

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to use different selectors to do that.

First you would have to add a `border-radius` to your parent `div`. I suggest you add a class or an ID to the parent element so your child divs won't be affected by the `border-radius`:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

```
.parent {
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

For the child elements, you can keep using the IDs to select the children. But you can also use the `first-child` and `last-child` pseudo-classes to style them.

```
.parent div:first-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

.parent div:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a selection problem. Everything is ok. I have dedicated CSS files which code that uniquely identifies the elements.

The problem is that the "rounded" corners are in the border and are not visible (of course, it's called `border-radius`, not `padding-radius` or `element-radius`). And I want to have a workaround to create a border (green), but also round the corners for the element excluding its border.

Comment: Oh, have you tried setting `overflow: hidden;` on the parent element? It could be that the child elements' background is overlapping on the rounded corners. Setting `overflow: hidden;` forces it to stay within the borders of the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply suitable padding to the containing div to achieve the target design:

```css
#wrapper
{
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  color: green;
  width: 8rem;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: green;
}
#first
{
  background-color: red;
  height: 4rem;
  border-radius: 1rem 1rem 0 0;
}
#second
{
  background-color: blue;
  height: 4rem;
  border-radius: 0 0 1rem 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="first">
    </div>
    <div id="second">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a working pen: https://codepen.io/jaycodist/pen/LYNVeON